# Can shape shapefiles (.shp) be imported into Panoply?

Tags: shapefile, panoply

I'm trying to open a shapefile of census-designated boundary (CDB) shapes into Panoply. The application seems to recognize the .shp format, but I nevertheless still get the error:

> There was an error opening the file 'counties.shp': Invalid value(s) in header of counties.shp.

However, there don't seem to be errors when I open this file in QGIS or ArcGIS. Is there a specific way that headers must be formatted, or can regular .shp files not be opened in Panoply? If the latter, what are my other options?

Comment: It would help if you provided the first 100 bytes of the `.shp` file.

Comment: @Vince Apologies, but how do you do this? I've printed the records in Python but I'm not so sure how to print the header.

Comment: The `od` utility of Linux would do it, or a 5-line block of Python the opens the file, reads all the bytes, slices the first 100, then prints them as hexadecimal (with spaces between bytes and a newline every eight or ten). Google "print binary file as hex in Python"